# React Native absolute image path

Tags: image, react-native, absolute-path

I have images in my app at appname/assets/<> and would like to refer to them with an absolute path since I may use them with multiple components in multiple relative locations. I know how to use `{require('../assets/image.png')}`, but I want to save the absolute path of the image as a string in a database to reference in many places. I just can't tell what to add ahead of "/assets/image.png" to create this absolute path. I've tried a couple of versions of "appname/assets/image.png" but I just can't figure it out. What does the full React Native file tree look like for an app? Thanks for your help.

Comment: try `require('./assets/image.png')`

Comment: As far as I understand file paths (which is not real well), that is still a relative reference.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. so maybe this can help you: https://github.com/mantrajs/babel-root-slash-import

Comment: also there is another way that i 'll post it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**#1-**
**Babel Root Import**

Babel plugin to change the behaviour of import to root based paths:

https://github.com/mantrajs/babel-root-slash-import

---

**#2-**
**Package.json**

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/3099#issuecomment-221815006

Comment: Arash, I appreciate your help. Option #2 is closest to what I was looking for. The github link was not quite sufficient to explain it for me so I will add the this additional resource (Medium article) that helped make a little more sense. I am very curious what the "name":"app" addition to package.json is replacing (i.e. what was the "name" by default and shouldn't I be able to just refer to that?). But adding that tiny simple line makes it function the way I need so I'm good. If someone else finds this and needs to talk through it, I'm happy to.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve that problem by this way.

Make sure that image files (bank.png, visa.png) are located in assets/img directory.

[image]

First, open your package.json File.

```
{
...
   "dependencies":{
    ...
    "react": "17.0.1",
    ...
    "react-native": "0.64.3",
    ...
    }
...
}
```

Second, add dev dependencies to use babel.

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.9",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^4.1.0"
  },
```

Third, create babel.config.js at the root directory of your project and add "@assets" in alias content of the module "babel-plugin-module-resolver".

```
module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ['babel-preset-expo'],
        plugins: [
            [
                require.resolve('babel-plugin-module-resolver'),
                {
                    root: ['./src/'],
                    alias: {                        
                        '@assets': './assets',
                    },
                },
            ],
            'react-native-reanimated/plugin',
        ],
    };
};
```

Fourth, in your component, import image using '@assets' alias.
(Eg: ItemList.js)

```
import { Image } from 'react-native';

import visa from '@assets/img/visa.png';
import bank from '@assets/img/bank.png';

function GetImage ({image}) {

   switch (image) {
            case 'visa': {
                return <Image source={visa} style={{ width: 80, resizeMode: 'contain' }} />;
            }           

            case 'bank': {
                return <Image source={bank} style={{ width: 30, resizeMode: 'contain' }} />;
            }

            default: {
                return <Image source={visa} style={{ width: 75, resizeMode: 'contain' }} />;
            }

   }

}

export default function ItemList () {
   return (

            <View
                style={{
                    alignItems: 'center',
                    justifyContent: 'center',
                    width: '100%',
                    alignItems: 'flex-start',
                }}
            >
                <GetImage image='bank'/>
                <GetImage image='visa'/>
                <GetImage />
            </View>
   )
}
```